# Generating raw SQL statements from binary SQL Server dump?

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to dig through a SQL Server database and the dump I've been given seems to be a binary file rather than the usual text-based SQL statement dump I'm used to with MySQL and Postgres.

Is this the usual way SQL Server databases are exported or is this some sort of problem? If the former, is it possible to turn this into the SQL text file that I'm used to so I can look through it? Or could I just ask the guy who gave it to me to export it in text rather than binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single thing that "MSSQL dump" might refer to really.

You need to know what you've actually been given. Is it an MSSQL backup file (usually a .bak) or simply a detached database (.mdf)?

If the former, it can be restored using SQL Management Studio, if the latter, it can just be re-attached.

There is no simple way to get from a backup to a SQL script of `INSERT` commands etc.  You will have to restore it onto a SQL server, then export to SQL either using DTS, or the SQL Server Management Studio.

Note, however, that there are **no guarantees** that the SQL will be compliant with MySQL or any other SQL product.

Comment: This was a .bak. So you're saying there's no way for me to get a text dump of the SQL statements like you get in MySQL? My plan was to grab data directly out of the file using a vim macro (and avoid actually using SQL server at all) but I obviously can't do that if there's no text file to parse.

Comment: You will need to restore to MSSQL first, then export to plain SQL.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Cylindric covers the likeliest situations. An unlikely option (and what I thought of first) is, if what you have is supposed to be a single data set (i.e. the contents of one table), it might have been produced with the BCP utility using "native format" (or perhaps Unicode native format). The only way to read that, I believe, is to BCP it back into a database.

By and large, when someone provides you with a set of data, they should also provide you with an explanation of what form and format that data is in. Even with XML, the "self-describing" data format, you should have an XLS sheet or something that lets you know what mystery tags like  < xzb > stands for.